# Obtaining conditional distribution from mixed model

Tags: normal-distribution, mixed-model, conditional-probability

Suppose you have the following mixed model:

$$y_{it} =X_{it} \beta + Z_{it}b_{i} + u_{it} \tag{1}$$

where $y_{it}$ is the response for a subject $i$ and time $t$, $X_{it}$ is a vector of features, $\beta$ is a coefficient, $Z_{it}$ describes random effects, $b_{i}$ are permanent effects and $u_{it}$ is a variable from a normal distribution $u_{i} \sim N(0, I\sigma^{2})$

Basically, I want to obtain the conditional distribution $p(y_{it}|\beta,b_{i})$.

As far as I know, equation $(1)$ for $y_{it}$ can be described as a normal distribution:

$$y_{it} \sim N(X_{it}\beta+Z_{it}b_{i},u_{it})$$

In order to obtain the conditional distribution, I would get the joint distribution

$$p(y_{it},u_{it}|\beta,b_{i}) = p(y_{it}|\beta, b_{i},u_{it} )p(u_{it})$$ and then integrate out $u_{it}$

$$\int p(y_{it},u_{it}|\beta,b_{i})du_{it} = p(y_{it}|\beta,b_{i})$$

However, I haven't been able to obtain the correct distribution: $$y_{it}|b_{i} = N(X_{it}\beta+Z_{it}b_{i}, \sigma^{2})$$

(I'm guessing the dependency on $\beta$ is implicit in this notation)

What am I missing?

This is the relevant part in Congdon's book "Applied Bayesian Hierarchical Methods":

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I just realized there is something very wrong with the normal prior for the variance. The variance can't be negative but the prior is centered on $0$. Maybe a change of distribution of $y_{it}$ is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely solution.

A different distribution for $y_{it}$ is simply take the first terms as constants. Then it is simply

$$y_{it}|b_{i} \sim X_{it}\beta + Z_{it}b_{i} + N(0, \sigma)$$

which is obviously

$$y_{it}|b_{i} \sim N(X_{it}\beta + Z_{it}b_{i} , \sigma)$$

However, surely this can't hold when $Z_{it}$ are selected from other distributions, although the book didn't consider that case.